# Toggle visibility of divs based on multiple checkboxes using AND operator

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm trying to toggle the visibility of lots of divs using checkboxes in multiple fieldsets, each of which has an ID that corresponds to a class on the div. I'm not super familiar with jQuery but I've almost got it working. The problem is that I want the checked values of each fieldset to operate on an AND basis instead of OR. This is my jQuery at the moment:

```
$(function () {
  $(':checkbox').change(function () {                
     $('.'+this.id).toggle(this.checked);
  }).change();
});
```

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MLJ4Q/1/)

When you check off Date 01 and Date 03 in the fiddle, both shows appear, which is correct. However, if you *also* check off Venue 01, show #2 still appears, because date 3 is still true (even though venue 1 is not true). I'm struggling to make show #2 disappear in this case (because it's not in venue 1, even though it is in date 3).

The actual fieldsets (there are 5) contain a ton of dynamically-generated options, so I'd rather not do it using a bunch of if statements/other manually typed code, if possible.

Comment: Can you clarify your rules?

Comment: If checkboxes are selected in just one fieldset, what I have in the fiddle is fine. If checkboxes are selected in more than one fieldset, however, I want the shows that appear to match the selected checkboxes in fieldset #1 AND in fieldset #2, not one or the other. Hopefully that makes sense! I can try including another example if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! So you need to do this in steps, because you really want both AND and OR, which creates a matrix of possible filtering.

So easy way is to select all the shows and then slowly knock off each show that doesn't fit the criteria.

Here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/MLJ4Q/4/

You'll have to extend it for your other filters if you have them. Could even be put into a loop for smaller code, but this is easiest to understand for a beginner.

```
$(function () {
  $(':checkbox').change(function () {                

       // we need to do this in steps, so first we need to get a string of classes for each filter
      var dates = $('.dates input:checked').map(function(){ return "." + this.value; }).get().join();
      var venues = $('.venues input:checked').map(function(){ return "." + this.value; }).get().join();
      var genres = $('.genres input:checked').map(function(){ return "." + this.value; }).get().join();


        // start with all shows
      var shows =  $('.show');

      // filter for dates if we need to
      if(dates) {
          shows = shows.filter(dates);
      }

      // filter for venues if we need to
      if(venues) {
        shows = shows.filter(venues);
      }

      // filter for genres if we need to
      if(genres) {
          shows = shows.filter(genres);
      }

      // hide everything      
      $('.show').hide();
      // show the ones we want. Pun intended
      shows.show();
      console.log(shows.length);



  });
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I totally owe you a beer next time I see you :)